# INotifyPropertyChanged Question in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, view, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

i am working on MVVM and i am not much familiar with it and i would like to know where to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

I implemented it in **ViewModel** (Which is correct from my understanding) and i am in a situation where i need to modify the retrieved data in the View and once the data is modified save it in a property and once the propriety in the View is assigned/changed i want the ComboBox pick up that itemsource which will be the property thats changed and holds the modified Data.

So what do i do in this situation? should i implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the View and use:

```
PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChanged_implimentation); ?
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view models. You may also choose to implement it on your models, if you need to notify any consumer of their property changes (for example view models).

You wouldn't typically implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view, as you would use XAML binding to communicate between your view and underlying view model.

`INPC` is required to notify your view to update itself whenever a property value changes in your view model. The binding engine will update the bound property values in your view model whenever a control value in your view changes.

A good introduction to MVVM can be found [here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx), and I would also strongly recommend using an [MVVM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913946/looking-for-the-wpf-mvvm-framework) for any kind of serious app.

Comment: We implement INotifyPropertyChanged and a helper method SendPropertyChanged( string propertyName ) in a 'ViewModelBase' class and inherit all ViewModels from that. Saves lots of tedious repetition.

Comment: Yes that is useful. If you use an MVVM framework such as Caliburn.Micro, it provides a view model base class with INPC implemented. There is also a helper method for invoking the PropertyChanged event which takes a lambda expression, so your codebase doesn't need to be littered with magic strings.